# How many total internal vertices does a full 5-ary tree with n vertices have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many total internal vertices does a full 5-ary tree with n vertices have?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem, what have you tried, and just where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s a tree, so it has $n-1$ edges. If you think of the edges as being oriented away from the root of the tree, each internal vertex is the ‘tail’ vertex of $5$ edges. Now put the pieces together to express the number of internal vertices in terms of $n$.